# unable to insert OpportunityLineItem.PricebookEntry

Tags: unit-test, pricebook

This is the code -

```java
Apex code - 
 public static void createnewOrderItem (OpportunityLineItem ChildOpptyLines,Id OrderId,Integer Qty){

        if(((ChildOpptyLines.NC__c > 0) && (ChildOpptyLines.NC__c != null))){
            customObj OI = new customObj();            
            OI.Quantity__c = Integer.valueof(ChildOpptyLines.Quantity);
            OI.Product__c = ChildOpptyLines.Product2Id;            
            OI.PriceBookId__c = ChildOpptyLines.PriceBookEntry.PriceBook2Id; 
            insertnewOrdBillItems.add(OI);
        }
        if(ChildOpptyLines.UnitPrice != null && ChildOpptyLines.UnitPrice > 0){            
            customObj OI = new customObj();
            OBI.Amount__c = ChildOpptyLines.UnitPrice;
            OI.Quantity__c = Integer.valueof(ChildOpptyLines.Quantity);
            OI.Product__c = ChildOpptyLines.Product2Id;
            OI.PriceBookId__c = ChildOpptyLines.PriceBookEntry.PriceBook2Id; 
            insertnewOrdBillItems.add(OI);        
        }

TestClassUtils Method
 public static OpportunityLineItem createOpportunityLineItem(Id opportunityId, Id pricebookEntryId)
    {
        
        return new OpportunityLineItem(  OpportunityId      = opportunityId
                                       , Quantity           = 5
                                       , PricebookEntryId   = pricebookEntryId
                                       , TotalPrice         = 1
                                       , product_Term__c    = 12);
    }
    

@TestSetup
static void setup(){

    Product2 prod = new Product2();
    prod.Name  = 'test prod';
    prod.Family = 'test';
    prod.IsActive = true;
        
    insert prod;
        
    Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
    PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = prod.Id,
        UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true);
    insert standardPrice;
         
    Pricebook2 customPB = new Pricebook2(Name='Custom Pricebook', isActive=true);
    insert customPB;
        
    PriceBookEntry PBE = new PriceBookEntry();
    PBE.Pricebook2Id = customPB.id;
    PBE.Product2Id = prod.Id;
    PBE.UnitPrice = 100;
    PBE.IsActive = true;
    insert PBE;
        
    OpportunityLineItem oli = TestClassUtils.createOpportunityLineItem(oppList[1].id,PBE.id);
    oli.NC__c = 1000;
    //  oli.unitPrice = 10000; //this also throws an error - System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: UnitPrice (only one of unit price or total price may be specified): [UnitPrice]
    insert oli;
}
        
@istest
private static void createnewpbRecs(){//This method throws this error - System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: OpportunityLineItem.PricebookEntry
    OpportunityLineItem ol = [Select id,NRC__c, UnitPrice, Quantity, Product2Id, Product_Term__c from OpportunityLineItem];
    List<Opportunity> childOptys = [Select id,name,Parent_Opportunity__c from Opportunity where Parent_Opportunity__c!=null];
    for(Opportunity o : childOptys){           
        createULOrder.createnewOrderBillingItem(ol,ord.id,10);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can format blocks of code by using 3 backticks (i.e. `\`\`\``) to mark both the start and end of your code. Alternatively, you can use your mouse to select all of your code text and then press `ctrl` + `k`, or click the `{}` button in the post editor.

Comment: The errors you're seeing are not directly caused by your unit test, but rather by the code that is called as a result of your unit test. More specifically, the issues are in `createULOrder.createnewOrderBillingItem()` and `TestClassUtils.createOpportunityLineItem()`. Whenever you're asking for help with an error, you should _always_ provide the full text of the error message (don't shorten/paraphrase it) as well as the stack trace. In nearly all cases, you'll also need to provide the code that the error is complaining about (here, that would be portions of `createULOrder` and `TestClassUtils`)

Comment: That was the exact error that I got in Dev Console. I havent changed anything. Also I have updated the code with the other methods that the test class is calling.

Comment: The stack trace is usually important too. That's the list of classes/methods and line numbers that were being executed when you ran into the error. Usually, it's only the topmost entry that matters, but in unit tests it could be a few entries lower on the stack trace. Thankfully, it looks like the sources of the errors are able to be seen based on the additional code you've added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into two errors. Thankfully, the error messages Salesforce emitted here are decent, and it should be fairly easy to see what the issues are if we examine those error messages.

#### First up, the error in your `@testSetup` method

The error you report is

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: UnitPrice (only one of unit price or total price may be specified): [UnitPrice]

As it says, when you insert an `OpportunityLineItem`, you may only set one of `UnitPrice` and `TotalPrice`.

Your `TestClassUtils.createOpportunityLineItem()` method is setting `TotalPrice`, and your `@testSetup` annotated method is setting `UnitPrice`.

You'll need to either not set `UnitPrice` in your test setup method, or set `TotalPrice` to null on the `OpportunityLineItem` that you get back from your test utility method. Given that the code you're testing references `UnitPrice`, I'd go for the latter.

In the end though, Salesforce sets one field based on the other (TotalPrice = UnitPrice * Quantity, or UnitPrice = TotalPrice / Quantity), so the decision you should make here is *whatever makes it easier for you to test and make assertions on*.

#### The error in the codee being tested

The error reported is

> System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: OpportunityLineItem.PricebookEntry

In your test method, your query for OpportunityLineItems includes the following fields:

- Id,
- NRC__c,
- UnitPrice,
- Quantity,
- Product2Id,
- Product_Term__c

In the code being tested by this test though, you're using `PriceBookEntry.PriceBook2Id`, which does not appear in the set of fields that you queried.

In tests, you are responsible for making sure that all of the data that the method you're testing requires to run is supplied. In this case, you need to add `PriceBookEntry.PriceBook2Id` to the query in your test method.

Comment: Thanks Derek. That worked.